# Loss and accuracy difference between .evaluate() and sklearn classification_report()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

There is an apparent difference between the `.evaluate()` metrics and sklearn `classification_report` when training a model in tensorflow. When training the model the history shows a good accuracy which is approximately the same when using `.evaluate()` but is totally different when using sklearn metrics.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

(ds_train, ds_test), ds_info = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split=['train', 'test'],
    shuffle_files=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    with_info=True,
)

def normalize_img(image, label):
  """Normalizes images: `uint8` -> `float32`."""
  return tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255., label

ds_train = ds_train.map(
    normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
ds_train = ds_train.cache()
ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(ds_info.splits['train'].num_examples)
ds_train = ds_train.batch(128)
ds_train = ds_train.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

ds_test = ds_test.map(
    normalize_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
ds_test = ds_test.batch(128)
ds_test = ds_test.cache()
ds_test = ds_test.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics='accuracy',
)

model.fit(
    ds_train,
    epochs=6,
    validation_data=ds_test,
)
```

```
Epoch 1/6
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.3586 - accuracy: 0.9009 - val_loss: 0.1961 - val_accuracy: 0.9435
Epoch 2/6
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1634 - accuracy: 0.9529 - val_loss: 0.1310 - val_accuracy: 0.9619
Epoch 3/6
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1142 - accuracy: 0.9676 - val_loss: 0.1089 - val_accuracy: 0.9670
Epoch 4/6
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0883 - accuracy: 0.9743 - val_loss: 0.0913 - val_accuracy: 0.9721
Epoch 5/6
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0709 - accuracy: 0.9795 - val_loss: 0.0795 - val_accuracy: 0.9772
Epoch 6/6
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0590 - accuracy: 0.9826 - val_loss: 0.0762 - val_accuracy: 0.9768
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x1a603d02070>
```

```py
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(ds_train)
print("Loss:", loss)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy)
```

```
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0484 - accuracy: 0.9867
Loss: 0.04843668267130852
Accuracy: 0.9867166876792908
```

```py
train_probs = model.predict(ds_train)

train_preds = tf.argmax(train_probs, axis=-1)
train_labels_ds = ds_train.map(lambda image, label: label).unbatch()
y_true = next(iter(train_labels_ds.batch(60000))).numpy()

print(classification_report(y_true, train_preds))
```

```
 precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.10      0.10      0.10      5923
           1       0.11      0.11      0.11      6742
           2       0.10      0.10      0.10      5958
           3       0.10      0.10      0.10      6131
           4       0.09      0.09      0.09      5842
           5       0.09      0.09      0.09      5421
           6       0.10      0.10      0.10      5918
           7       0.11      0.11      0.11      6265
           8       0.11      0.10      0.10      5851
           9       0.11      0.10      0.11      5949

    accuracy                           0.10     60000
   macro avg       0.10      0.10      0.10     60000
weighted avg       0.10      0.10      0.10     60000
```

As shown in the code the difference is clearly magnificent but can't seem to know the problem. I also tried using the metrics built in keras and I get the same results as sklearn.

Note: This code is from the tensorflow official documentation [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line to:

```
ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(ds_info.splits['train'].num_examples, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
```

By default, `reshuffle_each_iteration` is set to `True`. So that's causing label and prediction mismatch even if model is trained properly. From [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle)

> reshuffle_each_iteration =  A boolean, which if true indicates that
> the dataset should be pseudorandomly reshuffled each time it is
> iterated over. (Defaults to True.)

**Edit - Another Approach:** Iterate over the dataset to get preds and labels:

```
train_preds = np.array([])
y_true =  np.array([])

for x, y in ds_train:
  train_preds = np.concatenate([train_preds,
                       np.argmax(model(x), axis = -1)])
  y_true = np.concatenate([y_true, y.numpy()])
```

Comment: I tried it and still get the same problem.

Comment: It worked and got the expected results but what seems to be the problem ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what happens under the hood while shuffling, I think it is something about shuffle buffer.

Comment: My original problem was using ```.shuffle()``` with my validation set.